# Way of using find_all receiving function?

Tags: prolog

is there a way of using the `findall` function receiving another function as a parameter?

My problem is something like

```
enemy_area(Enemys,[X|Tail],Area) :-
   findall(A,(member(A,Enemys),adjacc(X,A)),Area).
```

(And then should come some type of recursion)

In which the `adjacc` function should return all the adjacent positions of a Points from a List (there several points in this list, and I want a union of all adjacents of these points).

Is there a way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a union, you can try sort/2 after findall/3.

Here is an exmple:

```
adjacc(a,b).
adjacc(a,c).
adjacc(b,c).
adjacc(b,d).
```

Now if you try:

```
?- findall(Y, (member(X,[a,b]),adjacc(X,Y)), L), sort(L, S).
```

You should get:

```
L = [b,c,c,d],
S = [b,c,d]
```

Bye